# Font issue in wordpress when i activate my own plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed a plugin and I enqueue bootstrap.min.css in admin for UI of my plugin. When I activated this plugin it affected the WordPress font in admin panel as shown in screenshots. What can I do?

[image] 
[image]

Comment: First thing you can do is to post the code here. Second thing is to provide a link to the site/page. It's an issue of multiple css conflicts. Simple solution is to prefix your custom CSS with some keyword.

Comment: wp_register_style('bootstrap_min', plugins_url( '/admin/css/bootstrap.min.css',__FILE__ ));
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_min');

Comment: Don't enqueue bootstrap css in your backend?

Comment: if i do this m UI will be completely break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strip all unnecessary styles from bootstrap css.
For starters, find all instances of font-family and remove them from the css.